# Python split string every nth char but only at linebreaks

Tags: python, teamspeak

Let me explain: I want to write a script for Teamspeak in python and i want to send splitted text messages. This is the code i got so far:

```
msg = [msg[i:i + 1024] for i in range(0, len(msg), 1024)]
for message in msg: ts3lib.requestSendPrivateTextMsg(schid, "{0}".format(message), clientID)
```

Please note that teamspeak's maximal character limit is 1024. but not really since some chars like ♠ use 3 chars of the character limit.

So what i want is to have it check where it would split at 1024 chars then go back to the last \n or . and split there.

Comment: Do you have an example of input and desired output?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, input would be https://github.com/Bluscream/pyTSon_plugins/blob/master/scripts/welcomeBot/__init__.py#L35 and output currently looks like: https://i.imgur.com/HSYnfAt.png

Comment: Don't expect people to read hundreds of line of code to solve a small problem. Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @FLab: No need to inspect all of my code. The line in question will be highlighted when you visit the link.

Comment: Do you want people to help you or not? Please update your question with **all** the information (not links) necessary to answer your question.